# Meaning of function (global) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to understand what **function (global)** means in code below, and is '**window**' the parameter value passed to the function or its the name of a parameter rather than the parameter value?

May be this is simple JavaScript using an uncommon style of coding.

```
(function (global) {
var mobileSkin = "",
    app = global.app = global.app || {};
    app.application = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, 
                      { layout: "tabstrip-layout", skin:"flat"});
})(window);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are common JavaScript patterns in this code:

- The namespace pattern.
- The immediate function pattern.

**The Namespace Pattern**

In a browser, the window object is the global scope object. In this example of code that you shared, the programmer created a [immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (IIFE) and passes the global object `window` as a parameter, which in the context of the IIFE is bound to the local variable `global`.

The function, as its names suggests, is immediately invoked when this file is parsed by the browser.

From this point on, `global` is just an alias for the global scope object `window`, and the programmer uses it to define a namespace `app` in it.

The namespace basically avoids cluttering the global scope with the objects you need to define and allows the programmer to be more in control of exactly what is defined within his custom scope.

The idea is that from this point forward, you should define all application globals within this customized scope and not within the window global scope, avoiding name collisions with other third-party libraries that you are using. This will be a pseudo-equivalent of packages or namespaces in other languages like Java or C#.

[Stoyan Stefanov](http://blog.stoyanstefanov.com/about/) in his book [JavaScript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752) explains it as follows:

> Namespaces help reduce the number of globals required by our programs
> and at the same time also help avoid naming collisions or excessive
> name prefixing.
>
> JavaScript doesn’t have namespaces built into the language syntax, but
> this is a feature that is quite easy to achieve. Instead of polluting
> the global scope with a lot of functions, objects, and other
> variables, you can create one (and ideally only one) global object for
> your application or library. Then you can add all the functionality to
> that object.

**The Immediately-Invoked Function Pattern**

The immediately-invoked function is another common JavaScript pattern. It is simply a function that is executed right after it is defined.

Stefanov describes its importance as follows:

> This pattern is useful because it provides a scope sandbox for your
> initialization code. Think about the following common scenario: Your
> code has to perform some setup tasks when the page loads, such as
> attaching event handlers, creating objects, and so on. All this work
> needs to be done only once, so there’s no reason to create a reusable
> named function. But the code also requires some temporary variables,
> which you won’t need after the initialization phase is complete. It
> would be a bad idea to create all those variables as globals. That’s
> why you need an immediate function—to wrap all your code in its local
> scope and not leak any variables in the global scope:
>
> ```
> (function () {
>    var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
>    today = new Date(),
>    msg = 'Today is ' + days[today.getDay()] + ', ' + today.getDate();
>    alert(msg);
> }()); // "Today is Fri, 13"
> ```
>
> If this code weren’t wrapped in an immediate function, then the
> variables days, today, and msg would all be global variables,
> leftovers from the initialization code.

Comment: Excellent Explanation. I appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: What does this mean: app = global.app = global.app || {};? Frankly, its very confusing and like a new language to me.

Comment: Interpret it from right to left. This part `global.app || {}` evaluates to the value of `global.app` if it exists, otherwise it evaluates to a new object. That value is the assigned to the `global.app` variable and for convenience it is aliased as the `app`. This last part is probably overkill, since the object is already accessible in the global scope with that name.

Comment: Ok.That makes it clear.Thanks. I feel its better to write simple code rather than such complex looking code. Simpler code is easier to maintain and quicker to develop/deliver.